# Python + Komodo Edit

Tags: python, scapy, komodoedit

I am trying to get scapy to auto complete in komodo edit with no success, has anyone successfully done this?

Thanks,
Python New Comer

Answer (score 1):

Autocomplete in Python is a hit or miss proposition.  It varies widely -- some things can be analyzed by Komodo and some can't.

If it won't autocomplete, it's probably because it relies on too many metaclass techniques that seem to baffle Komodo.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in virtualenv or have some tricky python paths you have to add additional import directories in:

> Preferences -> Languages -> Python ->
>   Additional Python Import Directories

Komodo can't understand these things out of the box.

Also make sure you have following option enabled:

> Preferences -> Code Intelligence ->
>       Include all files and directories from the project base directory

These steps would enable code completion to decent quality but as mentioned by S.Lott it is nearly impossible to implement full-featured auto-completion (like in Java or C#) in Python due its dynamic nature.